# When does usercontrol visible property affect its children?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a **ASP.NET userControl** that contains other controls. 
Sometimes, when changing the `visible` property of the usercontrol, it does change the visible value of its children, but sometimes it doesn't.

I thought it depended on the moment the property was changed during the page life cycle, cause it seemed to work well when changed in the `Page_PreRender` event, but I got a case when it didn't work.

Any idea, on how I could affect the visibility of all the controls of the user control just through the visible property of this one? I don't want to make a loop through all the children to set their visbile property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It never "affects" its children. Setting a parent to false does not change the `Visible` property of a child. However, when the page is rendered, if ANY parent object is set to false, none of the children will be rendered. The `Visible` property of a child will still show as true while going through the rendering process and debugging, but it will never render.

Comment: Sorry, but when debugging, in my prerender event, setting the usercontrol visible to true does immediately change the visible property of its children to the same value(either true or false)...But it is not done all the time, and that is the matter

Comment: @GianT971: I would say you have something different going on that isn't covered by your question. The property should not change as a result of a parent change. The behavior is dependent on the parent's property, but the setting itself shouldn't be.